# Need help extracting all transaction details from Paypal API in C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, paypal

I am trying to retrieve all my Paypal transactions via an API call in C#. I have read through the documentation and fiddled with things here and there, but I am relatively new to APIs in C# an d all. I am not exactly sure where to place the ClientID and Secret. I have tried to go through the OAuth2 documentation, but it isn't making a ton of sense.

I am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Curl and postman examples are here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-credentials

Such HTTPS requests can be adapted to any environment, including C#. Make sure you put the `clientid:secret` in an auth parameter provided by your HTTP library so that it will do the basic auth for you, or set the header yourself and give a username:password value that is base64 encoded as required for HTTP basic authentication.

Once you are getting an access token back, use it for a Transaction Reports API calls -- if that is what you truly want to integrate, although I would not recommend using an API for this.

---

Instead, the best solution is to use the paypal.com Activity -> "All Reports" to do an Activity Download in CSV format, and import that into your system.

After that, to be notified of new transactions in real time, it's best to do so at the moment you capture/execute a transaction on your server.  This would involve creating two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return JSON data, but the second route can check for success and record a successful transaction in your database (and any other business logic you need) before forwarding on its return JSON.

After creating those two routes that return JSON, pair them with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server